# Dragging in browser window works, but on mobile it is not changing. Responsive website

Tags: html, css

I can resize it and it works in my browser window, but when I go on mobile phone it is not resizing. What can be the problem?

webpage: gintarasarstikaitis.ucnstudents.com

Comment: <link href="css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

Comment: My media queries are: media all and (min-width: 480px) , media all and (min-width: 660px)

Comment: I don't have any problems with that page. The navigation goes down in mobile. (Honor 6, Android 5.1.1, Chrome)